# Position of buttons in rows, in a JPanel based 'menu bar'

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I'm trying Swing programming but I can't do what I want.

I would like to place a top bar button with 2 lines of button but I just have 1 line in my case.

Here is my code:

```
    Container contentPane = getContentPane(); 
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1000,500));
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(1000,500));

    JPanel panelButton = new JPanel();
    JPanel panelTopButton = new JPanel();
    JPanel panelBottomButton = new JPanel();

    panelTopButton.add(dashboard);
    panelTopButton.add(journal);
    panelTopButton.add(myPlans);
    panelTopButton.add(myFavorites);
    panelTopButton.add(shoppingCart);

    panelBottomButton.add(profile);
    panelBottomButton.add(notifications);

    panelButton.add(panelTopButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panelButton.add(panelBottomButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    contentPane.add(panelButton,BorderLayout.NORTH);

    //Display
    setSize(400,120);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

[I have this](http://hpics.li/d46a587)

[image]

And [I want this](http://hpics.li/6b8bf17)

[image]

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Take a look at my solution below.

Answer (score 2):

You need one panel for each line.

Try to do this:

```
JPanel panelButtonsL1 = new JPanel();
JPanel panelButtonsL2 = new JPanel();

panelButtonsL1.add(dashboard);
panelButtonsL1.add(journal);
panelButtonsL1.add(myPlans);
panelButtonsL1.add(myFavorites);
panelButtonsL1.add(shoppingCart);

panelButtonsL2.add(profile);
panelButtonsL2.add(notifications);
```

The default layour of `JPanel` is `FlowLayout`. Bear in mind that layout is very important to work with swing component disposition.

Define the bottom panel as `GridLayout`.

```
JPanel panelButton = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1)); // 2 rows x 1 column
panelButton.add(panelButtonsL1);
panelButton.add(panelButtonsL2);
```

Details of GridLayout you can find on [API.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html)

Comment: Surely you meant to write `panelButtonsL2.add(profile);` instead of panelButtonsL1?  And similarly for the line after that?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using a [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html): assign a `GridLayout` to panelButton with two rows and one column, and then add the two panels to it.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you want there is a simpler alternative by continue using the default ***FlowLayout*** from the panel. It is more appropriate than using ***GridLayout*** since you wanted the last 2 buttons to move to the next row and center itself.

If you use ***GridLayout***, the buttons at the next row are likely going to be directly below one of the buttons above. Here are 2 ways to get what you want.

---

**Method 1**. Reduce the width of the main panel holding your buttons:
Dosing so, you will have to add the main panel using `BorderLayout.CENTER`.

[image]

---

**Method 2**. Add the buttons to a sub-panel of smaller width and add it to the main panel. All your buttons will be added to the smaller sub-panel:

[image]